# PHP + MySql with dates to chart

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, mysql

Im trying to get values from MySql to javascript chart.

[image: Values]

Values goes like this at javascript:

0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0

Each 0 means value by own hour from 12AM to 11PM, in this case chart would be empty.

Question is, how I can fetch all values from MySql by current date to own hours?

In example picture, values should go like this:

2.7,0,0,2.2,0,0.......

In first value (2.7), both values from picture is counted together as its added in same hour in same date.

So, how do I get all values, count each hour together of current day and separate them to same form as I showed above?

I have no idea how to do this. I havent worked before with things like this.

Answer (score 1):

Use the MySQL DATE_FORMAT() function to extract just the date and hour and GROUP BY the resulting string, with a SUM(value).

Answer (score 0):

This will get you the values added together by hour and date. It will not include any values for the missing hours though.

```
SELECT DATE(date), HOUR(date), SUM(value)
FROM table1
GROUP BY DATE(date), HOUR(date)
```

Comment: Any ideas how to make array of 24 values with missing hours also?

Comment: For that you need a "calendar table". This is populated with all the datapoints (so one row for every day and hour of the day). You then query that table as your main table and perform a LEFT JOIN to the table containing your real data. This gives you an entry for every hour of every day.